# How do I check SSL certificate when using Cloudflare DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, lets-encrypt, cloudflare, certbot

So usually I just create a letsencrypt certificate and setup it up, then i open up the browser and click the "LOCK" icon and check the certificate info, this tells me that my setup actually worked and was installed correctly.

What I ran into today, is that I am doing this for a domain name that is using Cloudflare DNS, so Cloudflare sits between the browser and the server/site. When I click the "LOCK" icon, i see Cloudflare SSL info.

What is the best approach to validate that the letsencrypt cert is actually working on the server/site side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a free cloudflare plan you cannot import your own SSL certificate.

The only option inside the cloudflare account is to disable the proxy for the "A" record (and/or other appropriate DNS records). Once set, requests will bypass cloudflare and show the original server's IP address, the server's available SSL certificate will also be used.

Comment: But that way, won't Cloudflare be bypassed? Unless he does it temporarily, just to check and revert the records back later.

Comment: @Krackout, I agree, i really just need to be able to check that the other side of the proxy is actually encrypted and using the correct cert.

Answer (score 3):

One can use `curl` to connect directly to the origin server:

```
curl -v --resolve www.example.com:443:ip.of.origin.server https://www.example.com
```

The `--resolve` argument tells `curl` to bypass DNS request for `www.example.com` for port 443 (TLS) connections, and instead use `ip.of.origin.server` as the destination address.

Another option is to add an entry for your domain and origin server in `/etc/hosts` (Linux) or `c:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Drivers\etc\hosts.txt`. After one can check the connection with any tool.

Comment: Or `openssl s_client -connect $address:$port -servername $hostname | openssl x509 -noout -text` connects directly to the address but allows you specify what the FQDN 'would have been' for SNI